# c# Remove Everything that does not match regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm facing a problem.

I have a regex: `^(?!.*word\/...\/ .*).+$` replace with nothing

This regex works on notepad++

When I try to use it on c# it does not work. It leaves the file unchanged

this is how I do it:

```
string x = Regex.Replace(filestring, "^(?!.*word\\/...\\/ .*).+$", "");
```

edit: and yes I output string `x`

Comment: Do you have an example of the string you're trying to search and what you want removed from it?

Comment: Can you add an "@" at the beginning of the expression? It could be that your slashes are being escaped rather than being treated as literals... It would look like `string x = Regex.Replace(filestring, @"^(?!.*word\\/...\\/ .*).+$", "");
`

Comment: I noticed that your regex uses ^ and $ -- does your text editor have Multiline turned on by default? If so, you'll need to specify `RegexOptions.Multiline`. Also consider IgnoreCase.

Comment: @PedroC88 Nope does not work

Comment: So did specifying Multiline as @kjhf suggested work for you? As a side note, I highly recommend using [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) for testing/creating Regex. It allows you to play with the data and use recipes, and will generate the equivalent C# code for you (including things like the Multiline option)

Comment: @TylerHundley yes it did work. also thanks for the suggestion of LinqPad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, adding: `RegexOptions.Multiline` Fixed it. Thanks to @kjhf